# Parsing error: Unexpected token in JSX, trying to implement react-simple-typewriter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

Creating a portfolio website as an exercise and trying out different animations.

Been going through this document, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-typewriter, and searched online as well to get a feel for what to use.

So far, I've tried it as a component prop, it worked, but the loop would not continue after the first animation.

Found a tip online to use as a hook instead, could not get it to even show, as well as throw the above mentioned error.

```
import "./intro.scss"
import React from 'react'
import { useTypewriter } from 'react-simple-typewriter';

export default function Intro() {

 
  const MyComponent = () => {
 
    const {text} = useTypewriter({
      words: ['Hello', 'From', 'Typewriter', 'Hook!'],
      loop: {3}
    })

  return (
    <div className="intro" id="intro">
        <div className="left">
         <div className="imgContainer">

            <img src="assets/stoned1.png" alt=""/>

         </div>
          
        </div>

        <div className="right">
          
          <div className="wrapper">
            <h2>Hello, I'm</h2>
            <h1>STONEd_NFT</h1>
            <h3>Freelance </h3>
          </div>

          <a href="#portfolio">
            <img src="assets/down.png" alt=""/>
          </a>
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}
}
```

When loaded on localhost:3000, this is what shows.:
[image: When loaded on localhost:3000, this is what shows.]

Comment: `loop: {3}` is not valid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix two things:

- `loop: {3}` is not a valid syntax, should be only `loop: 3`
- you need to pass `text` to your component

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

---

```
import React from "react";
import { useTypewriter } from "react-simple-typewriter";

export default function App() {
  const { text } = useTypewriter({
    words: ["Hello", " I'm STONEd_NFT", "Freelance"],
    loop: 3
  });

  return (
    <div className="intro" id="intro">
      <div className="left">
        <div className="imgContainer">
          <img src="assets/stoned1.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="right">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <h1>{text}</h1>
        </div>
        <a href="#portfolio">
          <img src="assets/down.png" alt="" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing value: [3] or {value: 3}
the json object is not val

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).